# String stores data from unrelated memory address

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to generate a string of 50 dots. I have the following code:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string s(".",50);
  cout << s;
  }
```

and the output is:

```
.vector::_M_realloc_insert$C����pX�%
```

The string `s` doesn't store `.` 50 times, but some other part of memory. A leak happened, and I have no idea how.

What went wrong? How do I go about generating a string of length n consisting only of dots? In general, I want to do in c++ what in python would be done by `"c"*n.`

Thank you.

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) more carefully.  The constructor you want is `std::string s(50, '.');`.  And next time, please remove anything irrelevant (i.e. 95% of it) from the code you post, see [mre].

Comment: ok ty. i didnt know what was the minimal reproducible data since the print out referred to vec, etc. removed everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example could be a whole lot shorter, and still have the same problem.

The problem is that with the [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you use, the length is the length of the string `"."`, not how long the `std::string` should be. Since `"."` is not `50` characters long, you will have *undefined behavior*.

From the linked reference for constructor number 4 (the one you use):

> The behavior is undefined if `[s, s + count)` is not a valid range

There `s` is the string `"."` and `count` is the value `50`.

The constructor I ***guess*** you want to use is the one taking a single *character* instead of a string (number 2 in the linked reference):

```
std::string s(50, '.');  // Fill string with 50 dots
```